# Passing in a function which increments elements of boost::fusion:vector

Tags: c++, boost

I found the following code which I am using as a basis. It describes how to populate a boost::fusion::vector with the values 6:

```
#include <boost/fusion/algorithm.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/container.hpp>

struct F {
    F(int blah): blah(blah){}

    template <typename T>
    void operator()(T& t) const {
        t = blah;
    }

    int blah;
};

template <typename T>
void apply_for_each_to_assign(T &t)
{
    boost::fusion::for_each(t, F(6));
}

int main() {
    boost::fusion::vector<int, double, int> idi;
    apply_for_each_to_assign(idi);
}
```

My question is this, instead of populating every element with the value 6- what would be the neatest way to have every element incrementing by one? So

```
v[0] = 1
v[1] = 2
```

etc? I presume I would need to write an increment function but I am not sure how I need to incorporate it in to the above code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`fold`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/algorithm/iteration/functions/fold.html).

`fold` takes a function `A f(A, B)` where `B` is your element type, and a intial `A` value and call it on all the elements. It is rougly equivalent to `f(f(f(initial, first_elem), second_elem), third_elem)`.

You should declare the functor like this:

```
struct accumulator
{
    typedef int result_type;

    template<typename T>
    int operator()(int value, T& t) const
    {
        t += value;
        return value + 1;
    }
};
```

And here's the usage:

```
template <typename T>
void apply_for_each_to_assign(T &t)
{
    boost::fusion::fold(t, 1, accumulator());        
}
```

Here a whole example with printing:

```
#include <boost/fusion/algorithm/iteration/fold.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/algorithm/iteration/for_each.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/fold.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/container.hpp>
#include <iostream>

struct accumulator
{
    typedef int result_type;

    template<typename T>
    int operator()(int value, T& t) const
    {
        t += value;
        return value + 1;
    }
};

struct Print {
    template <typename T>
    void operator()(T& t) const {
        std::cout << t << std::endl;
    }
};

template <typename T>
void apply_for_each_to_assign(T &t)
{
    boost::fusion::fold(t, 1, accumulator());        
    boost::fusion::for_each(t, Print());
}

int main() 
{
    boost::fusion::vector<int, double, int> idi;
    apply_for_each_to_assign(idi);
}
```